# What does -? mean in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I came across this line in the [type definitions for `prop-types`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/14d0a6329aaf71eaa43e6d87e43e6ec74ea17c1c/types/prop-types/index.d.ts#L27):

```ts
export type ValidationMap<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: Validator<T[K]> };
```

Without `-` it would be a pretty standard partial [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), but I can't find anywhere in the docs where it talks about `-?`.

Can anyone explain what `-?` means?

Comment: Updated docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers

Answer (score 119, accepted):

`+` or `-` allows control over the mapped type modifier (`?` or `readonly`). `-?` means must be all present, aka it removes *optionality* (`?`) e.g.:

```
type T = {
    a: string
    b?: string
}


// Note b is optional
const sameAsT: { [K in keyof T]: string } = {
    a: 'asdf', // a is required
}

// Note a became optional
const canBeNotPresent: { [K in keyof T]?: string } = {
}

// Note b became required
const mustBePreset: { [K in keyof T]-?: string } = {
    a: 'asdf', 
    b: 'asdf'  // b became required 
}
```

## More

I did a lesson on these mapped type modifiers : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zgWo_gnzVI

Comment: I'm geeking out a bit that it's you who answered (I'm halfway through your book).  :)  Is this covered in your book or in the TypeScript docs anywhere?

Comment: Check this document from typescript [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) it provides more insight on other information about function and parameter.

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors sadly not yet https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/issues/402

Comment: @basarat no worries :)  Thanks for the quick answer here!  I'm enjoying your book 

Comment: Maybe worth noting when this syntax wast introduced: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/commit/a629acd8fd4844742fdd01ab6cf55afa9377db0e

And the names used for the symbols: `MappedTypeModifiers`.

Comment: Huh? what does `+?` do? Is it equivalent to just `?` -- Edit: The answer is yes (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers)

Answer (score 1):

Read `-?` as `remove optionality`, which makes it required. [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) is the current official documentation.