# Use of subtract operator and in keyword in the implementation of typescript Required<T>

Tags: typescript

I found this is how `Required<T>` is implemented in typescript:

```
type Required<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: T[P];
};
```

Just wondering, are there other typical usecase of the `in` keyword other than iterating through the properties in a type?

Secondly, this use of `-` looks like a magic to me. Are there any other usecase of this `-`?

Comment: See this for `-`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52417131

Answer (score 2):

The `-` removes the `?` modifier that made the property optional--making the property not optional if it was before. The `in` operator [has uses in JavaScript but iterating through a type's properties is its only TypeScript use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214731/what-does-the-in-keyword-do-in-typescript).