# Why can't use function to assert that var is not null in typescript

Tags: typescript

I was playing around with typescript and I noticed something unexpected.
I can see in `showCarInfo2` function an error

[image]

Why can't I use function for non null assertions?

In the first function `showCarInfo1` there is `car.passengers !== null` and everything works fine.

```
interface Car {
  name: string;
  passengers: string[] | null;
}

const car: Car = {
  name: 'Seat',
  passengers: ['Andrew', 'Kate'],
}

function showCarInfo1(car: Car) {
  if(car.passengers !== null) {
    console.log(`${car.name}${car.passengers.map(passenger => ` ,${passenger}` )}`)
  } else {
    console.log(car.name)
  }
}

showCarInfo1(car)

const hasPassengers = (car: Car) => car.passengers !== null;

function showCarInfo2(car: Car) {
  if(hasPassengers(car)) {
    console.log(`${car.name}${car.passengers.map(passenger => ` ,${passenger}` )}`)
  } else {
    console.log(car.name)
  }
}
```

Comment: In most cases, checks in TypeScript are non-transitive. If you do, for example `x = foo !== null; if (x) { foo++}` you'd still get an error. It's a common problem and a known issue. Walking through the transitive conditionals and inferring types through them is apparently very costly for the compiler.

Comment: @VLAZ Is there any good solution or should I always use assertions like ` car.passengers !== null` even if I have to do this in multiple places?

Comment: You can create a [user defined type-guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). But you also need some supporting infrastructure around it. I'll try to post an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler does not perform [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) across function boundaries.  While it would be nice if the compiler could do so, it would be prohibitively expensive.  In general the compiler would have to do the equivalent of emulating every possible way the program could be run before it could make conclusions about the types, and assuming you want programs to compile before the heat death of the universe, there will be limitations.  For a good discussion about this, see [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998), "Trade-offs in Control Flow Analysis".

In the absence of this happening automatically, there is a technique you can use to tell the compiler that the intent of `hasPassengers` acts as a type guard on its argument.  You can annotate it as a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).  The return type is a *type predicate* of the form `arg is Type` and it's a special subtype of `boolean` (so user-defined type guards only work for functions that return `boolean`):

```
interface NonNullCar extends Car {
  passengers: string[];
}

const hasPassengers = (car: Car): car is NonNullCar => car.passengers !== null;
```

If you make the above change, your code will compile as desired:

```
function showCarInfo2(car: Car) {
  if (hasPassengers(car)) {
    console.log(`${car.name}${car.passengers.map(passenger => ` ,${passenger}`)}`) // no error
  } else {
    console.log(car.name)
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#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)

Answer (score 1):

You can create [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) that checks if an arbitrary property of an object is present. To do that, you need a supporting generic type:

```
type HasProperty<T extends object, K extends keyof T> = T & { [P in K]-?: Exclude<T[K], null | undefined> };
```

This is a generic type that takes anything, as well as a key `K` of it as generics and with the [`Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) and [the `-?` mapped type modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417131/what-does-mean-in-typescript) constructs a type that has the same keys except:

- Always has `K`
- `K` is never `null`
- `K` is never `undefined`.

In essence

```
type CarWithPassangers = HasProperty<Car, "passengers">
```

is like defining

```
interface CarWithPassangers {
  name: string;
  passengers: string[]
}
```

With this type, you can create a generic type guard:

```
const hasProperty = <T extends object, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, prop: K) : obj is HasProperty<T, K>  =>
    prop in obj 
        && obj[prop] !== null
        && obj[prop] !== undefined;
```

And finally use it like this:

```
function showCarInfo(car: Car) {
  if(hasProperty(car, "passengers")) {
    console.log(`${car.name}${car.passengers.map(passenger => ` ,${passenger}` )}`)
  } else {
    console.log(car.name)
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwAoCcD2kWgDwBUoQAewEAdgCYJRoBGAVhAMbAA0UA0gcWZVANYQQaAGZRcAPigBeMVABkUAN5QA2kigBLUhwC6AWgD8ALigBRQowA2AV3IQ8K9jralrly1AA+UaxQjCtCHJJAF8AbgAoCMY0UgRgKAALRFQMCCwQaSg8LhIKKloGZjZOIjzeASFRCQAKQpNcNjB0MBN2AEooE0LNKnhkFvScRo5JaXEIqCmoZoxNbR7J6eW5BUKVWbAdKABCKRlXdyXlqdXqeg2W7b2ZXzsA0iDIiK0SFGE4RmgAYTgUJSWpDgAFsICZ4igtABzSJTMCIBBkKHpBDg4CQ0hQlTbbyHSyREJRYS+ZgaWJQBCJNAAd1+KAAkqRhGgaow-iY6Z1FEsNMIaskBmkMqy-mwAETwhCIzEosXtLnHKAxOJoSwQAB0ljQUJqAAMACSKNkodVA0EhQ3G9WS6XIlAIdXAuBgGo2pHpcZQXVQFiGt0ylAhb3tIPtJYhAiWREA5bKhCqjVanVWs0QMNTQmEiJAA)