# Can't pass an object to a function because one value is optional while the function requires it

Tags: typescript

To be clear `TypeClasses` is a type of object document I deal with. It is actually called a typeclass in real life for the project I am working on. This does not refer to a type or a class in typescript, so sorry for the confusing name.

I have the following function:

```
  const handleUpdateDeck = async (updatedDeck: FixedDeck | HoistableDeck) => {
    const updatedTypeClass = getUpdatedTypeClassWithNewDeck(
      typeClass,
      updatedDeck,
      selectedZoneID
    );

    if (updatedTypeClass._id && "_id" in updatedTypeClass) {
      try {
        await handleUpdateTypeClass(updatedTypeClass);
      } catch (err: any) {
        console.log("Updating deck failed: ", err.message);
      }
    } else {
      setTypeClass(updatedTypeClass);
    }
  };
```

I use the function `getUpdatedTypeClassWithNewDeck` to update type-classes both when a new one is being added and worked on, and when updating an existing document.

Because of that, this function will except and return object either with or without an `_id`.

After I do get that updated object - if it has an `_id`, I know it is an existing document, and I want to update it in my database using the function `handleUpdateTypeClass`, and if not, I simply want to update the local state using `setTypeClass`.

My issue is, `handleUpdateTypeClass` will only except type-classes WITH an `_id`, an because the `_id` is optional, it complains.

> Types of property '_id' are incompatible.
> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

As you can see in my code, I am trying to assure to the function that the _id key definitaly exists, both with `updatedTypeClass._id` and with `"_id" in updatedTypeClass`, but it still complains. How can I get rid of that?

EDIT: to clarify, as it was asked. TypeClass is to a boat what a model is to  a car.
A typeClass has zones.
Zones have decks.

The function `getUpdatedTypeClassWithNewDeck` just returns a new and complete typeClass object after a deck is being edited. It needs to find that deck in the right zone, and it something I do in different places in my code, so just extracted that logic to a different function.

This is the function. It makes no CRUD operations, simply returns an updated object.

```
export default function (
  typeClass: Omit<TypeClass, "_id"> & { _id?: string },
  updatedDeck: FixedDeck | HoistableDeck,
  selectedZoneID: string
) {
  return {
    ...typeClass,
    zones: typeClass.zones.map((zone) => {
      if (zone._id === selectedZoneID) {
        const zoneToUpdate: Zone | undefined = typeClass.zones.find(
          (z) => z._id === selectedZoneID
        );

        if (!zoneToUpdate) {
          throw new Error("failed to find zone to update");
        }
        const updatedZone: Zone = {
          ...zoneToUpdate,
          decks: zoneToUpdate.decks.map((deck) =>
            deck._id === updatedDeck._id ? updatedDeck : deck
          ),
        };
        return updatedZone;
      } else {
        return zone;
      }
    }),
  };
}
```

The component to build or edit a typeclass in my system is fairly complex, so I use it both for creating and editing which works perfectly fine. I just handle the saving differently based on if the object has an ID or not.
If it doesn't have an ID I simply change the state locally. If it does, then I make an update on the server - and then update it locally in the state.

EDIT 2: This is my TypeClass type.

```
export type TypeClass = {
  _id: string;

  // The name of the type class
  name: string;

  // How many zones does this type class have?
  zones: Zone[];
};

export type Zone = {
  _id: string;

  // The name of the zone
  name: string;

  // How many decks are in the zone? This number includes the fixed bottom deck
  // Can be one only
  decks: (FixedDeck | HoistableDeck)[];
};
```

Then there's the type for the decks but that really doesn't matter.

My component to configure a Type-class expects the object to be received as a prop, so this is how I defined it in my props:

```
  typeClass: Omit<TypeClass, "_id"> & { _id?: string };
```

And lastly, this is my handleUpdatTypeClass function:

```
  const handleUpdateTypeClass = async (tc: TypeClass) => {
    try {
      if (!updateTypeClass) {
        throw new Error("Update function undefined");
      }
      if (!tc) {
        throw new Error("Couldn't find type-class");
      }

      if (tc.name.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("name|Can't leave name empty");
      }

      if (tc.zones.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("zones|Type-classes must have at least one zone");
      }

      setErrors({});
      setIsSubmitting(true);

      await updateTypeClass(tc);
      setTypeClass(tc);
    } catch (err: any) {
      throw new Error(err.message);
    } finally {
      setIsSubmitting(false);
    }
  };
```

Comment: You should show us what a `TypeClass` is, in which circumstances it has or doesn't have an `_id` and how updates affect this aspect, but maybe if it doesn't have an `_id` it should really be a `TypeClassDraft` or something. I think you should also replace that CRUD logic with functions capturing intent:  this will make it a lot easier for you to surface the correct types and to add features later.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wje0vW)? [I have an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66477883) that covers it.

Comment: Sure, any type guard would do. Just to be clear: having an `_id` doesn't mean it doesn't have the value `undefined`, and TS would not narrow `updatedTypeClass` even if you wrote `updatedTypeClass._id !== undefined` because that check concerns the `_id` prop and TS won't make this info bubble up to characterise  `updateTypeClass` itself. However, there is probably a way to model the domain so that the need for this kind of check disappears

Comment: since you are dealing with both create AND update as a separate flows, it would only make sense to create a base Class dto (or Interface, depends on your design) for `create` object with all required fields and a separate one for `update` that will extend the `create` dto and add the `_id` field as required

Comment: @geoffrey thank you, I've added more details.  Going over @VLAZ answer meanwhile though I'll admit it is extremely abstract for my current knowledge. As a band aid I've been adding `as TypeClass` but that feels just like that - a simple band aid.

Comment: @VLAZ ok it was a bit intimidating at first as it is super abstract, but even though I don't understand what's going on it works haha. Thank you!

Comment: @GoranLegenda that doesn't solve the problem, though - *either* of the two can be returned by `getUpdatedTypeClassWithNewDeck` and you'd still need to find out which one you have. Which needs compile-time check to ensure it.