# How to pass optional parameters while enforcing one to be passed in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I am writing a function that expects to receive **only one** of the configs in `SubNodeConfig`. Understand I can make all of them optional by doing the following below but would like to instead make one of them compulsory eg. using the non-null assertion operator `!` perhaps.

```js
export interface SubNodeConfig {
    alphaConfig?: AlphaConfig;
    betaConfig?: BetaConfig;
    charlieConfig?: CharlieConfig;
    deltaConfig?: DeltaConfig;
}

export interface MainNode {
    id: number;
    config: SubNodeConfig;
}
```

Context in which I intended it to be used:

```js
const getUpdated = (
    originalNodes: MainNode[],
    updatedConfig: SubNodeConfig 
) => {
    const updatedNodes= [...originalNodes];

    updatedNodes[indexOfNodeToUpdate] = {
        id: 123456,
        config: updatedConfig,
    };

    return updatedNodes;
};
```

Have also tried to look at the TypeScript [utility docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html), but I may have missed something, thanks.

Comment: Can't you use a Union type for SubNodeConfig?

i.e.:
`type SubNodeConfig = AlphaConfig | BetaConfig | CharlieConfig | DeltaConfig`

Comment: I tried `type SubNodeConfig = AlphaConfig | BetaConfig | CharlieConfig | DeltaConfig | undefined` - and there was a red squiggly prompt suggesting: "The expected type comes from property `config` which is declared here on type `MainNode`" thanks for this anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses a self-indexing [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) in combination with the [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) and [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) utility types:

```
type AlphaConfig = { alpha: 'a' };
type BetaConfig = { beta: 'b' };
type CharlieConfig = { charlie: 'c' };
type DeltaConfig = { delta: 'd' };

interface SubNodeConfig {
    alphaConfig?: AlphaConfig;
    betaConfig?: BetaConfig;
    charlieConfig?: CharlieConfig;
    deltaConfig?: DeltaConfig;
}

type RequireOne<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>>;
}[keyof T]

const x: RequireOne<SubNodeConfig> = { alphaConfig: { alpha: 'a' } }; // OK
const y: RequireOne<SubNodeConfig> = {
  alphaConfig: { alpha: 'a' },
  betaConfig: { beta: 'b' }
}; // OK
const z: RequireOne<SubNodeConfig> = {}; // Error
```

---

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=50&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNmAFgQwMIHsB2AzAlgcygF4oBvKZBFALigHJk6oBfAbgFgAoUSKAIQjA0WPIRLkARoOS06Epmy49oqFACc4uCBhwFiZKAGN1miLMMKO3cNAAiEOEJ2j95ACYOhst5a5dcmMAQatjIhtAAygCuEgBy6B7OeqRcUGkUVMK6+AD8tPBIWaJW6VBSTiIEefzSSfgl6cbIGlp11arNpnUNaR6ORVW09v3dXMx+1rwAShAAjlG4ahAA8pgQADwAKgB8rqnpANoA0lABUADWECDo2FCbALoAtNUz84sQbusACriG51sAGigR222yszAOl2utweE0MWAAzsAoAAPWivBZLVYbaJxBLaSr4XbiDKFOq0ciUQqyRgsFisKAAekZUGWRy48MwSKgIHRc0xKzW61x8UShOJBipKHJksyNIUQPKA3wFLK0lk8jpbCZLLZHMRyIAXny3lihSL8XUJaRtcyoABRNRqdBqLhAA)

Comment: Possible to execute the above using `interface AlphaConfig` instead of `type AlphaConfig`? 

Also, for those curious about `-?`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417131/what-does-mean-in-typescript

Comment: @jchua Just tested. Works exactly the same when using interfaces.